# Joining 3 grouped values

Tags: sql

I have 3 queries that counts for each company, number of rows during certain month, from 3 different tables, and returning the same columns :qty,  month and company_name.

Instead of this I need to return 1 table with same 3 columns but qty must sum the value of all the 3 separated queries.

Can you suggest the best way to join or execute it in which I will not loose speed of execution.

Here is example of one of queries, the other 2 queries has exactly the same syntax, just instead `T_CUSTSK`, they use `T_CUSTSK2` and `T_CUSTSK3`:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) as qty, 
    DATEPART (MONTH, [start_date]) AS [month], 
    T_SYSCOM.company_name
FROM
    T_CUSTSK
INNER JOIN 
    T_SYSCOM ON T_CUSTSK.company_id = T_SYSCOM.company_id
WHERE
    DATEPART (MONTH, [start_date]) = 12
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART (MONTH, [start_date]), T_SYSCOM.company_name
ORDER BY
    month, qty DESC
```

Comment: Can u post some sample input and output?

Comment: Could you post the table schema of T_CUSTSK and T_SYSCOM table?

Comment: company name is varchar(100), qty int

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Union all will combine your queries.
You can then wrap your statement with another query that sums:

```
select sum(qty), month, company_name from (
Select count(*) as qty, datepart(month, [start_date]) as [month], T_SYSCOM.company_name
from T_CUSTSK
INNER JOIN T_SYSCOM
ON T_CUSTSK.company_id=T_SYSCOM.company_id
where datepart(month, [start_date])=12
group by datepart(month, [start_date]), T_SYSCOM.company_name
order by month, qty DESC

union all 

<second query>

union all

<third query> )

group by month, company_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this you could do UNION ALL of all the T_CUSTSKx tables in the subquery and join that result once with T_SYSCOM table.
I'm assuming the start_date is in T_CUSTSK table

```
Select count(*) as qty, datepart(month, [start_date]) as [month], T2.company_name
from (
SELECT company_id,start_date FROM T_CUSTSK
UNION ALL
SELECT company_id,start_date FROM T_CUSTSK2
UNION ALL
SELECT company_id,start_date FROM T_CUSTSK3
) T1
INNER JOIN @T_SYSCOM T2
    ON T1.company_id=T2.company_id
where datepart(month, [start_date])=12
group by datepart(month, [start_date]), T2.company_name
order by month, qty DESC
```

kindly let me know if this works

Comment: i should mention that in the 2 queries each date field has different name. start_date1, start_date2, start_date3

Comment: If the fields are of different name, then you set the column name as start_date in the inner sub query.  ""SELECT company_id,start_date1 AS start_date FROM T_CUSTSK
UNION ALL
SELECT company_id,start_date2 AS start_date FROM T_CUSTSK1
UNION ALL
SELECT company_id,start_date3 AS start_date FROM T_CUSTSK2""